# Is there any 'native' method that can give information about a character in the string?

Tags: python-3.x, string, character

I want to check a character in the string if it's a number, space, upper/lower character or a special character ".'*^?..."

I came up with the solution that is not very slick, plus it can't check for special characters without adding extra lines in else statement.

```
def checker(str1):
if str1.isspace() is True:
    print('it\'s a space')
if str1.isupper() is True:
    print('it\'s a letter and it\'s upper')
if str1.islower() is True:
    print('it\'s a letter and it\'s lower')
if str1.isdigit() is True:
    print('it\'s a digit')
if str1.isascii() is True:
    print('it\'s a special chracter')

string_letter = 'A'

checker(string_letter)
```

this code works... if I create some extra clause for special characters because right now it's just saying that space is a special character... it happens because `.isascii()` just too broad for special characters.

Is there any native method that I miss that can do that functionality more elegantly? aka give information on a character in the string?

I am very new to python, so I'm sorry, maybe I was not able to find native solution because I am not very fluent in terminology yet.

Comment: instead of `if x is True` just use `if x`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I didn't know that you could skip clarification and it would still work that way... great tip, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `elif` and place the special character checker to the last.

```
def checker(str1):
    if str1.isspace():
        print('it\'s a space')
    elif str1.isupper():
        print('it\'s a letter and it\'s upper')
    elif str1.islower():
        print('it\'s a letter and it\'s lower')
    elif str1.isdigit():
        print('it\'s a digit')
    elif str1.isascii():
        print('it\'s a special chracter')

string_letter = '&'

checker(string_letter)
```

Then,

```
it's a special chracter
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, so I suppose there is no build-in function like that?

Comment: Yeap, AFAIK there is no way to recognize only the special characters.